# How to find what functions are bound to UI events in a third party webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to debug a third party webpage which includes lots of javascript files.  There isn't any javascript code in the page itself.

I would like to see what code will get executed when I click on a link.  I can right click the link and inspect the html element, but how can I find what code will actually get executed when the link is clicked?

I'm using Chrome and Firefox, so a solution that works on either is fine.

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561546/finding-bounded-events-in-inspector), but that is asking specifically about inspector, whereas I don't really mind how the events are found (e.g. one option could be to use wget to download all the sources and the grep to search for the bindings - that would be ok if it works!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome: Right click on an element, inspect.  Far right, there's an Event Listeners section.

Comment: Ah, looks good.  I can see the jquery source attached as an event listener.  To find the application's handler, do I need to step through the jquery code to find the application code?

Comment: I expand the tree down and see if the info there is helpful.  If it isn't, then yes, you'll have to step through and trace as you go.

Answer (score 1):

In Firebug you can use the command [`getEventListeners()`](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/GetEventListeners) or install the extension [Eventbug](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions#Eventbug) and have a look at its *Events* panel.

In future versions of Firebug it might be that the functionality of Eventbug will be integrated, so that it's working like in the Chrome DevTools. See [issue 5440](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5440).